# Is it possible to row-reverse in a 2 columns Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-flexbox

I create a 2 columns FLatlist in react-native-android

```
1    |    2
------------
3    |    4
```

I want this

```
2    |    1
4    |    3
```

I try these:

```
<View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
        <FlatList
            style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}
```

and in render item I use `flexDirection:'row-reverse'` too

but no success!

Comment: Was it originally called `row`?

Comment: I answered your question below. If my answer helped you, I would appreciate an upvote and/or marking it as accepted answer or any other feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can use `flexDirection: 'row-reverse'` inside [`columnWrapperStyle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#columnwrapperstyle) :

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={2}
  columnWrapperStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse' }}
  data={data}
  renderItem={yourRenderFunction}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to just modify the order of your data:

For example you can introduce a `arrayMove` function which does the reordering.

**Example:**

```js
  const data = [
        { 
          'id': 1 
        },
        { 
          'id': 2
        },
        { 
          'id': 3
        },
        { 
          'id': 4
        } 
   ];
  
  
function arrayMove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
  var element = arr[fromIndex];
  arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
  arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
}
console.log('data', data);
arrayMove(data, 1, 0);
arrayMove(data, 3, 2);
console.log('data permutated', data);
```

**[image: Output:]**

**Working Expo:**

https://snack.expo.io/ryeNv5S2E

Comment: I agree with @Tim's solution. Unfortunately, FlatList doesn't support this way of ordering. I have created a demo - https://snack.expo.io/@hristoeftimov/reverse-blocks. It has a property `inverted`, but it reverses the items from bottom to top. `FlexDirection` and `FlexWrap` are not supported from Flatlist. So, the only solution is to change the order of the items :)

Comment: @HristoEftimov thanks for your feedback. In addition,  I would appreciate an upvote ;)

Comment: sure. You got it :)